# QGIS status line wrong coordinate format

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, mouse-position

I have a QGIS [2.14.5.LTR] project with crs EPSG:31468 which has metric units. In the status line at the bottom of QGIS main window the coordinates are displayed in degree lat/lon:

[image]

However, when switching from coordinates to extent the format is correct:

[image]

Bug? Feature? Am I missing some hidden secret settings?

Comment: I can't reproduce with a demo layer that I made myself from WKT `POLYGON ((
        4423384.47113164 496475.03926097, 
        4423387.542725174 496476.1016166282, 
        4423390.267898384 496472.19861431874, 
        4423384.586605081 496471.71362586605, 
        4423384.47113164 496475.03926097
    ))`. Could you put a small vector file available for testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Project -> Project Properties -> General tab`, you can select the coordinate display to be map units or degrees.

Switching to `Map Units` should bring back the units in meters, as you are used to from earlier versions. This is a new feature, not a bug.